# The cube is thrown twice. Determine the probability

Tags: probability

The cube is thrown twice. Determine the probability that:

a) none of the results should be 4

b) at least one of the results is 4

My attemp is:

a) $P(A)=\frac{35}{36}$

b) $P(A)=\frac{1}{36}$

but i didnt know that it is correct. please help me.thanks for my hard

Comment: By cube I suppose you mean a fair die?  What are the faces of that die --- five faces of 4 and one face "other"?

Comment: its my results correct, or not

Comment: Count the accepted drawings from the possible equiprobable drawings below: $$11,12,13,14,15,16,\\21,22,23,24,25,26,\\31,32,33,34,35,36,\\41,42,43,44,45,46,\\51,52,53,54,55,56,\\61,62,63,64,65,66.$$

Comment: i know that sir

Comment: If this comment is addressing me, what is the result of your counting ?

Comment: yes, you sir, i know that pairs, $n(\Omega)=36$

Comment: I am telling you to count the accepted drawings !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If none of the results can be $4$, then each dice has $5$ choices. This means there is a probability of $\frac{25}{36}$.

The second problem is just the complement of the first, which is $1-\frac{25}{36}=\frac{11}{36}$

Comment: I can not understand you well, you say, since the cube has 6 possibilities, this is not the result 4, that is, there are only 5 possibilities left, or not, my question is, the cube is thrown twice, ie the pairs are ranked (1, 1), (1,2) and so on, so that no result is 4 or this is only possible once in case (2,2)

Comment: Since each dice cannot be $4$, they can only be five numbers: $1,2,3,5,6$. So as long as both dice are one of these $5$ numbers, we will not have any $4$'s. Hence, there are a total of $5$ valid choices for each dice. Since we are rolling $2$ dice, this is $5^2$ total valid rolls.

Comment: I think I understood you, thanks